# Unable to start Genymotion due to network adapter

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

Have installed and reinstalled Genymotion and VB for several times and now on the latest releases of both of them.
When I try to start genymotion it fails and leaves a trace in logs:

```
[debug] [VBox] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
[debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostonlyifs")
[debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
[warning] [VBox] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] Checking "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" interface status (  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.150" )  )
[debug] [VBox] Empty interface name
[debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
[debug] [VBox] Call: ("hostonlyif", "create")
[debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
[debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] Interface "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2" created with success
```

Have no idea why it doesn't like the existing one and what `Empty interface name` means. Then it tries to start a fresh one, but fails because by default it has a 0.0.0.0 IP.

```
[critical] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2" configuration is not valid. Subnet: "0.0.0" . Mask: "0.0.0.0"
[debug] [VBox] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] Deleting "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2" host-only interface
[debug] [VBox] Call: ("hostonlyif", "remove", "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2")
[debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
[debug] [VBox] erase host.only.interface
[critical] [VBox] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from C:/Program Files/Genymobile/Genymotion/plugins/"
[critical] VM Engine failed to load, state 4
[critical] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.
[debug] [LogCollector] VM engine not available
```

It all looks like a conflict between VB and Genymotion. But hav no idea how to solve it.
Already tried different versions for VB bridged driver, cleaning registry and reinstalling them both. No luck.
Is there a way to get more detailed debug then in thoose loogs? Really interested why default network interface doesn't fit to VB. 
**Trying solution with deleting all net interfaces**

```
 [debug] [VBox] Path from registry: "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
 [debug] [VBox] Path: "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
 [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostinfo")
 [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
 [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4
 [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2
 [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
 [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Max memory size: 16320
 [debug] [VBox] get "" from host.only.interface
 [debug] [VBox] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
 [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostonlyifs")
 [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
 [debug] [VBox] Empty interface name
 [debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
 [debug] [VBox] Call: ("hostonlyif", "create")
 [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
 [debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] Interface "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" created with success
............
 [critical] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" configuration is not valid. Subnet: "0.0.0" . Mask: "0.0.0.0"
 [debug] [VBox] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] Deleting "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" host-only interface
 [debug] [VBox] Call: ("hostonlyif", "remove", "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter")
 [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
 [debug] [VBox] erase host.only.interface
 [critical] [VBox] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from C:/Program Files/Genymobile/Genymotion/plugins/"
 [critical] VM Engine failed to load, state 4
 [critical] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.
```

I wonder what is checked during

```
[Genymotion] [warning] [VBox] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] Checking "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" interface status (  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.1" )  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah! I did it! 
Due to my luck I found in the VB network connection settings a driver from Wireshark, added there automatically "NPCAP Packet Driver". After I removed it, everything started working like a charm!
[image]

Comment: Please report this to Npcap's issues on GitHub: https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues

Comment: Dunno if it's an Npcap problem, though Genymotion team is already informed about that. Btw an ordinary Debian is running OK with the config provided.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `Empty interface name` message, it looks like one of VirtualBox hostonly network interfaces is in a weird state. Maybe you can try this:

- Quit Genymotion
- Start VirtualBox
- Open the preferences panel (Ctrl+G)
- Go to "Network" > "Host-only Networks"
- Delete all interfaces here
- Start Genymotion again

[image: Host-only Networks preferences]

Comment: No luck. Already tried it - the same behaviour. Tries to create a new interface and fails because of invalid default settings.

Comment: Ah OK. Then maybe you can try to fix the hostonly interface definition: the log says `[critical] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" configuration is not valid. Subnet: "0.0.0" . Mask: "0.0.0.0"`: try to edit the interface and set the netmask to something like 255.255.255.0. Also check the DHCP server is enabled.

Comment: It was what I started with - both `192.168.56.1|150` with correct DHCP configured. It's mentioned in initial log as `Checking "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" interface status (  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.150" )  )`. You know, the only thing I haven't tried - running a random virtual machine on this installation (not from Genymotion). I'll give it a try.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you using? For Windows the recommended version is 5.0.28 (cf https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions)

Comment: I started with the version supplied with genymotion by default, then switched to the latest. Now I'm on 5.0.28 again but with the same result.